# Не работает проверка пользователя через текстовый документ (vk_api, Python)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Решил сделать команду !бан для бота в ВКонтакте. То есть, исключает пользователя из беседы. Сделал ещё так, чтобы после исключения, ID пользователя записывался в текстовой документ. Всё работает хорошо, бот исключает и записывает в текстовой документ. Но, у меня стоит, как раз на это проверка. Если пользователь, который зашёл в чат и находится в этом текстовом документе, то бот его исключает из беседы. Проверка почему-то не работает, именно с проверкой на ID. Объясните, что не так. Ошибок в консоли ни каких нету.

Код:

```
 if request[0:5] == "!бан " and user_id in admin:

            try:
                vk.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=request[5:])
            except:
                write_msg(vk, chat_id, '- Шо то не так, попробуй указать правильный ID пользователя.')

            id = request[5:]
            addBanUser = open("banlist.txt", "a")
            addBanUser.write(id + '\n')
            addBanUser.close()

    if event.type == VkChatEventType.USER_JOINED and event.from_chat:

        user_id = event.object.get('from_id')
        chat_id = event.chat_id

        with open("banlist.txt", "a") as CheckBanUsers:
            id = CheckBanUsers.readlines()

        if user_id in id:

            vk.messages.send(
                chat_id=chat_id,
                message='- Извините, вам запрещено тут находиться. Вы были забанены.'
            )

            vk.messages.removeChatUser(
                chat_id=chat_id,
                user_id=user_id
            )
```

Comment: Учитесь дебажить. Сравните ваш `user_id` и то, что возвращается из `CheckBanUsers.readlines()`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, а вот на счёт проверки, то что условение `in` я правильно поставил?

Comment: Правильно. Но проверьте, что у Вас находится в `id`.

Comment: `readlines()` считывает строки **вместе** с символом переноса строки. Таким образом `"12345" != "12345\n"`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, `Таким образом "12345" != "12345\n"`, - Не понял.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, `str.rstrip([chars])  -> str`, а если вот это использовать?

Comment: Можно это. Я бы на Вашем месте воспользовался модулем `pickle` или `json` для сериализации и десериализации объектов.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, да `pickle` мне тоже рекомендовали. А вот `json`, я что-то не очень понимаю, как с ним работать.